# Can I use groups and excludedGroups in maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: maven, junit, categories, surefire

Can I annotate a test class annotated with a Category for inclusion and then annotate certain test methods with another Category for exclusion?

I tried the following but it just uses the groups to include the test classes. Then surefire does not even take into account the 'excludedGroups' annotated methods within the test classes.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>surefire-integration-tests</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Include these classes -->
            <groups>my.test.category.IncludeTheseClasses</groups>
            <!-- Exclude these test methods -->
            <excludedGroups>my.test.category.IgnoreTheseMethods</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Comment: where did you read that excludedGroups exist?
PS. here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html  ))

Answer (score 0):

<groups> and <excludeGroups> contain tags, not classes.